# Clarification of Dynamic, Static, and Equal-Time Spin Susceptibilities

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, spin-models

I am trying to better understand the meaning of various spin susceptibility functions used in condensed matter physics especially in neutron scattering experiments.

In the following definitions, $\omega$ represents Matsubara frequencies, $\tau$ is imaginary time and subscripts $i,j$ represent the lattice site :

1. **Dynamic Spin-Susceptibility**:
   $$\chi_{ij}(\omega) = \int_{0}^{\beta} d\tau e^{i\tau\omega} \langle S_i(\tau) \cdot S_j(0) \rangle $$
2. **Static Spin-Susceptibility**:
   $$ \chi_{ij}(\omega=0) = \int_{0}^{\beta} d\tau \langle S_i(\tau) \cdot S_j(0) \rangle $$
3. **Equal-Time Spin Susceptibility**:
   $$ \chi_{ij}(\tau=0) = \int d\omega \chi_{ij}(\omega) $$

I understand that the static spin susceptibility in momentum space is useful in neutron scattering experiments and that the equal-time spin susceptibility provides insights into the instantaneous correlation between two spin sites. However, I am struggling to interpret the dynamic spin susceptibility for finite Matsubara frequencies, as they seem to lack a direct physical correspondence.

What would be the correct interpration of these three functions?